# TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined after deploy on heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, cloudinary

I'm using multer-storage-cloudinary for uploading the images ,then get the image url generated by cloudinary which will be save to mongoDB Cloud Service. I have tried run on the localhost and working fine. But, after I deploy to heroku, I'm got these messages when I run command `heroku logs --tail`

```
2020-10-15T06:20:08.110693+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
```

Here's my code :

**Controller**

```
async (req, res, _next) => {
await Models.Users.user_detail.create(
  {
    gender: req.body.gender,
    birth_date: req.body.birth_date,
    image_URL: req.file.path,
    created_at: moment(),
    user_id: req.body.user_id,
  },
  (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json(SERVER_ERROR(err));
    } else {
      res.json(OK("data successfully added"));
    }
  }
)
```

**Routes**

```
router.post(
"/detail/create",
multer({ storage: Storage.storageConfig }).single("image_URL"),
UserDetail.create)
```

**Storage Config**

```
new CloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary: cloudinary.v2,
    params: {
      folder: async (req, file) => "user",
    },
  })
```

**Cloudinary Config**

```
import cloudinary from "cloudinary"

cloudinary.v2.config({
  cloud_name: global.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
  api_key: global.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: global.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
})
export default cloudinary
```

Can anyone explain me why ? Thank you !

Comment: Based on the error it appears that there was no file as part of the request as (req.file is undefined). Can you log value of the "req" object to inspect it's content when it fails?

Comment: when I log "req", it not return the file path. But, I confused because when I tested at the local server, this endpoint work properly.